# angularjs - javascript code after importing angular.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularJs. I don't uderstand why the following code doesn't work. The file myjavascriptcode.js isn't loaded in the browser. if a switch
`"<script src="./myjavascriptcode.js"></script>"` before angular import, the file `myjavascriptcode` is loaded, but i get the exception `"angular is not defined"`. The only way to get it working is put 
`"<script src="../../angular-1.5.8/angular.js"></script>"` before the html tag.

**jsdemo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>To do</title>

       <script src="../../angular-1.2.5/angular.js" />  
       <script src="./myjavascriptcode.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        This is a simple example
    </body>        
</html>
```

**./myjavascriptcode.js**

```
function printMessage(unknownObject){
    if( angular.isFunction(unknownObject) ){
        unknownObject();
    }else{
        console.log("mi hai passato una variabile not function");
    }
};

var variable1 = function sayHello(){
    console.log("Hello");
}

var variable2 = "GoodBye!";


printMessage(variable1);
printMessage(variable2);

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular  tag is not closed correctly, That's why your javascript is not loaded

```
 <script src="../../angular-1.2.5/angular.js"></script>  
 <script src="./myjavascriptcode.js"></script>
```